# Convert this code to LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Sorry, Im just picking up LINQ and am relatively new at it.

Is it possible to convert the following into LINQ?

```
    foreach (DataRow row in results.Rows)
    {
        if (row["REMARKS"].ToString() == "Passes" || row["REMARKS"].ToString() == "Promoted")
        {
            result = String.Concat(result,row["ROLL_NO"].ToString()," ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks guys.. that was really quick of you ppl..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We don't know what the initial value of `result` is which makes this tricky, but assuming you actually just want a space-separated list, I'd do this:

```
var query = from DataRow row in result.Rows
            let remarks = row["REMARKS"].ToString()
            where remarks == "Passes" || remarks == "Promoted"
            select row["ROLL_NO"].ToString();

string results = string.Join(" ", query);
```

(Note that `DataTable` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<DataRow>`, which is why I've used an explicitly typed range variable. An alternative would be to call `result.Rows.AsEnumerable()` and make `row` implicitly typed.)

The final line is assuming .NET 4, which has more overloads for `string.Join` than earlier versions. Otherwise, this would do it:

```
string results = string.Join(" ", query.ToArray());
```

Of course, if you're using LINQ then you may well want to move away from `DataTable` etc to start with and use LINQ to SQL, Entity Framework, nHibernate or any of the other options available :)

Comment: yep.. this is the simplest to read, which is why i wanted to shift to linq in the first place. Thanks Jon! BTW what do you mean by moving away from Datatable etc?

Comment: I guess he means moving over to LINQ to SQL instead of using a DataTable to fetch the data, and LINQ to process it afterwards. Pure LINQ to SQL will make this whole thing even more readable, and will allow you to emit the code for actually fetching the data into the datatable.

Comment: Okay that sounds interesting - after seeing this answer, the first thing I did was to purchase "C#-in depth" and download the ebook!

Comment: @Roopesh: I hope it lives up to your expectations :)

Comment: @Jon, could you try answering this one as well? http://stackoverflow.com/q/4428008/297964.. its an extension of this question.

Comment: @Roopesh: I'll try to have a look later, but I don't have time right now.

Comment: @Jon: Yep, no problem.. Whenever you have the time.. Thanks!

Comment: don't forget about linq to dataset. gives you your AsEnumerable() as well as some extension methods on data rows.

Answer (score 2):

```
results.Rows
       .Cast<DataRow>() // If you need this line or not depends on the type of result.Rows
       .Where(row => row["REMARKS"].ToString() == "Passes" ||
                     row["REMARKS"].ToString() == "Promoted")
       .Aggregate(result, (acc, row) => String.Concat(acc, row["ROLL_NO"].ToString()," "))
```

Comment: I like this better than my answer, it is a pure LINQ implementation

Answer (score 1):

```
result = results.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(row => row["REMARKS"].ToString() == "Passes" || row["REMARKS"].ToString() == "Promoted").Aggregate(result, (current, row) => String.Concat(current, row["ROLL_NO"].ToString(), " "));
```

Comment: +1 - cos this works, but i really love jons answer for its simplicity and readability!

Answer (score 0):

```
string.Join(" ", result.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(r => r["REMARKS"].ToString() == "Passes" || r["REMARKS"].ToString() == "Promoted").Select(r => r["ROLL_NO"].ToString()).ToArray());
```

Comment: This won't compile - you either need a call to `Cast<DataRow>` or use `Rows.AsEnumerable()` - as `DataTable` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<DataRow>`.